# New System - Compatibile Hardware

Tags: graphics, webcam

I am planning to get new system and assemble myself. Need your input in building new machine.

Please let me know, which company's product will work with Ubuntu (I know, it works with almost all of them out of the box). But still needs your input on this.

Graphic Card
Web Camera (Which works with GTalk)

Thanks & Regards,
Anand

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/ - Ubuntu Certified Desktop Hardware
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/ - Ubuntu Certified Server Hardware

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/ - For a more extensive list on Certified Hardware and "Friendly" Hardware.

This has multiple lists, and usually is certified or gives supports based on a family of products.  A bit of research should allow you to put a list together for your new system.  Good Luck.